# Templating and OpenMP causes free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: c++, templates, openmp, stdvector, free

I've worked for a while to get my code to a minimal reproducible example and I think I have it. See the single `main.cpp` function below, compiled (on Linux) one of two ways:

1. In serial: `g++ -O3 --std=c++17  -o test_rho.exe main.cpp`
2. With OpenMP: `g++ -O3 --std=c++17 -fopenmp -o test_rho.exe main.cpp`

**Without** OpenMP the code runs fine. **With** OpenMP, I get the following error:

```
About to return 0
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

When using OpenMP, the following changes to `main.cpp` will make this error go away:

- Don't define `Wfn()` constructor. More specifically, don't invoke `_chi.resize(120)`.
- Don't use `private _chi` in the OpenMP loop.
- Don't use templating (instead just use `double` on everything).

What is causing a double free here and why do each of the changes above fix the problem?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Wfn class
template<typename real>
class Wfn {
    public:
        Wfn() { _chi.resize(120); }
        std::vector<real> rho(int nrhos);

    private:
        std::vector<real> _chi;
};

// Single Wfn function.
template<typename real>
std::vector<real> Wfn<real>::rho(int nrhos) {
    std::vector<real> rhos;
    rhos.resize(nrhos);
    #pragma omp parallel for private (_chi)
    for (size_t irho = 0; irho < nrhos; irho++) {
        rhos[irho] = (real)irho;
    }
    return rhos;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Wfn<double> wfn;
    std::vector<double> rhovs;

    rhovs = wfn.rho(1000);

    std::cerr << "About to return 0" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update**:

In case this helps, the general reason this is happening is because `wfn` is going out of scope, but my original question(s) still remain(s). If main is changed to:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {   
        Wfn<double> wfn;
        std::vector<double> rhovs;

        rhovs = wfn.rho(1000);
        std::cerr << "About to exit scope" << std::endl;
    }   

    std::cerr << "About to return 0" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then the error is

```
About to exit scope
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
```

Comment: I think you have found a bug in g++. No error in clang. I think it is related to `private(_chi)` clause when a private vector is created for each thread, but not properly freed.

Comment: Yap, I also think this is a bug. If you wrap `_chi` in a helper and print when the constructor and destructor is called, you will see that gcc calls the destructor of `this->_chi` when the function `rho()` returns, for whatever reason. See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8h5b9n79x). Seemingly, to trigger the bug one needs a templated class and a member variable needs to be passed via the `private` clause. Curious...

Comment: Please report an issue to the GCC team so they can be aware of the possible bug and be sure this is actually a bug (and not an undefined behaviour).